# Replacing values in a data frame with values in a second data frame if satisfies a condition

Tags: r, replace, dataframe, logic, conditional-statements

I have two data frames: "bim2"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyFqq.jpg)

and "illum".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3j4V.jpg)

If V2 of bim2 match with illum V1 (`match(bim2$V2, illum$V1)`), I want to replace `bim$V2` with the value in `illum$V2`. If it doesn't match (`bim2$V2` not equal to `illum$V1`), I want to keep the original values in `bim$V2`.

I've used

```
bim2$V2 <- illum$V2[match(bim2$V2, illum$V1)]
```

but it replaces the "`bim2$V2` not equal to `illum$V1`" by NAs.

Comment: Are they the same size? Could you provide a sample?

Comment: Please take a second read through your question. you say your data.frame is bim,  but you are using bim2 in your code. Also make sure that the description of the replacement is correct. It does not line up with your `match` code: `illum$v1` for example.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This will help you write great R questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @akash87 same size, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your given code, you can do :

```
bim2$V2[match(bim2$V7, illum$V1)] <- illum$V2[match(bim2$V7, illum$V1)]
```

It will replace the values that match, and keep the rest of the values. I hope, that works

Comment: @GorrilleiFalciani It will keep the values that doesn't match and replace only the one when bim2$V7 and illum$V1 match